# Slim Framework passing data to Twig view

Tags: php, slim

I'm trying to build a page in Slim that will bring up a subscribers details. I've worked out how to create the route and the relevant method in the controller which all works correctly. I'm using Twig for the views and can't work out how I would access the subscriber from the view.

**Route**

```
$app->get('/subscriber/{id}', 'SubscriberController:getSubscriber');
```

**Subscriber controller**

```
public function getSubscriber($request, $response, $args)
{
    $subscriber = Subscriber::where('id', $args['id'])->first();
}
```

I've been using the below in my controller to render my Twig templates

```
return $this->container->view->render($response, 'subscriber.twig');
```

How would I pass in or access my subscriber variable  in the Twig template? I can't work out how to pass it through?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On the render method the 3. parameter is `data` where you can give the twig template variables.

```
$data = ['subscriber' => $subscriber];
return $this->container->view->render($response, 'subscriber.twig', $data);
```

now you can access this variable inside twig.

Comment: Incredible there is not information in the doc of slim framework about tha name of the variable to be used in the view object. Thank you for the answer.